# GetChangedDocumentAsync returns null but should have a value

Tags: roslyn-code-analysis

My CodeFix returns a Document and I can trace it through Roslyn until GetChangeSolutionAsync. When I view in debugger ChangedDocument has a Document with the correct text. But the next line compares ChangedDocument == null and it is null and exits the routine returning null instead of my document.

I have stepped through GetChangedSoultionAsync and see it returning the correct value in the debugger but then see it return with null

```cs
       protected async virtual Task<Solution> GetChangedSolutionAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var changedDocument = await GetChangedDocumentAsync(cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
            if (changedDocument == null)
            {
                return null;
            }

            return changedDocument.Project.Solution;
        }
```

In debugger changedDocument after the await is shown below

> ?changedDocument
>   Test0.vb
>      DocumentState: {Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.DocumentState}
>      FilePath: null
>      Id: (DocumentId, #860a1da9-991f-4262-9428-c50c7a9a912e - Test0.vb)
>      Name: "Test0.vb"
>      Project: TestProject
>      Services: {Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.DefaultTextDocumentServiceProvider}
>      SourceCodeKind: Regular
>      State: {Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.DocumentState}
>   But the if statement is true and the function returns null

Comment: After a lot more debugging found what leads to above issue

Comment: I rolled back to a working version and when I upgrade Roslyn from 2.4 to 2.9 it breaks without changing any of my code. Is there a list of breaking changes for Roslyn CodeAnalysis?